# Getting error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dbnull

I want to get the subtotal of each **BusType**.  My problem now is that I'm getting the error `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types`. I do get the result on DataTable when I put the Breakpoint on `return ds`. When I try to proceed it displays that error `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to orther types`. How can I solve this?

```
var query = (from _transaction in _entities.Transactions
    join _cd in _entities.Organisations on _transaction.Refno equals _cd.Refno
    join _b in _entities.BusinessType on _transaction.BusinessTypeCode equals _b.BusinessTypeCode
              group new
              {
                  _trans = _transaction,
                   cd = _cd,
               }
               by new { _transaction.BusinessTypeCode,_transaction.Refno, _cd.BusinessName, _b.Description } into _group
               orderby _group.Key.BusinessTypeCode
               select new
                       {
                          BusinessTypeCode = _group.Key.BusinessTypeCode,
                          BusType = _group.Key.BusinessTypeCode + " - " +_group.Key.Description,
                          BusName = _group.Key.BusinessName,
                          BusL = _group.Sum(x=>x._trans.BusL),
                          BusInterrest = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.BusInterrest),
                          BusAdmin = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.BusAdmin),
                          BusPenalty = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.BusPenalty),
                          TotalBusCollected =_group.Sum(x=>x._trans.TotalBusCollected)
                       });
                DataTable dt=new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Tables.Add(query.CopyToDataTable());
                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                dt=ds.Tables[0];
    double BusL=0; double BusInterrest=0; double BusAdmin=0;
    double BusPenalty=0; double TotalBusCollected=0; string Title = string.Empty;
for(int i=0; i<=dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
  if(i > 0)
  {
     if(dt.Rows[i]["BusType"].ToString().ToLower() != dt.Rows[i]]["BusType"].ToString().ToLower())
     {
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.NewRow(),i);
        dt.Rows[i]["BusType"]=Title,
        Title = string.Empty;        
        dt.Rows[i]["BusL"]=BusL;
        BusL=0;
        dt.Rows[i]["BusInterrest"]=BusInterrest;
        BusInterrest=0;
        dt.Rows[i]["BusAdmin"]=BusAdmin;
        BusAdmin=0;
        dt.Rows[i]["BusPenalty"]=BusPenalty;
        BusPenalty=0;
        dt.Rows[i]["TotalBusCollected"]=TotaBusCollected;
        TotalBusCollected=0;
        i++;
     }
   }
   Title = "Subtotal for "+dt.Rows[i]["BusType"];
   BusL +=Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["BusL"]);
   BusInterrest+=Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["BusInterrest"]);
   BusAdmin+=Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["BusAdmin"]);
   BusPenalty+=Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["BusPenalty"]);
   TotalBusCollected+=Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["TotalBusCollected"])
}
        return ds;
```

**Needed Output**

```
   BusType     |BusName   | BusL  |BusInterest|BusAdmin| BusPenalty|TotalBusCollected
1 - ACCOUNTING |HIGHVELD  |-23.91 | 0         |-22.84  | 0         |-46.75
1 - ACCOUNTING |BHP       |-50.81 |-79.21     |-76     |-20.02     |-226.04
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
Sub Total                 |-74.72 |-79.21     |-98.84  |-20.02     |-272.79
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
 2 - FOOD      |SAB       |-14.18 |-435.97    |-2.57   |-67.55     |-520.27
 2 - FOOD      |DISTIL    |-43.05 |0          |-66,59  |0          |-109.64
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
Sub Total                 |-57.23 |-435.97    |-69.16  |-67.55     |-629.91
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
3 - MINING     |ANGLOGOLD |-4.43  |0          |-72     |0          |-76.43
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
Sub Total                 |-4.43  |0          |-72     |0          |-76.43
```

Comment: Where do you assign your dataset to datatable? All I see is `DataTable dt = new DataTable()` and then you start iterating over the empty table

Comment: @AlexanderDerck in this part `ds.Tables.Add(query.CopyToDataTable());ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";` it where I assign my dataset I am using DataSetLinqOperator.

Comment: Oh I see, `"Table1"` is default name for a datatable or something? My bad

Comment: @AlexanderDerck `Table1` there I am giving the dataTable name. I am naming my table.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain in the ass, but I read this on msdn: `To add tables to the collection, use Add method of the DataTableCollection. To remove tables, use the Remove method.` You do indeed add a table and give it a name, but you *nowhere* say that table is `dt` so how can you iterate over it? Please enlighten me :p

Comment: I believe Alexander is right though. You create a new DataTable and a new DataSet. Then you get a (new) DataTable from your query and add that to the DataSet. Then you name the table in the DataSet.

However you never set dt to the DataTable you created from the query.So perhaps you might want to write DataTable dt = query.CopyToDataTable(); and add that to the DataSet.

I don't think the error is connected to that though. I'd assume that query.CopyToDataTable() is throwing the Exception.

Comment: @OliverUlm I am sorry  guys I forgot to add this line in my code. I see now what you was talking about. This line it do exist in my code `dt = ds.Table[0];`. I have added it.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I am sorry  guys I forgot to add this line in my code. I see now what you was talking about. This line it do exist in my code `dt = ds.Table[0];`. I have added it. I updated my code.

Comment: **Where** do you get the error message?

Answer (score 1):

check for null first then use it based on that.

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows[i]["BusType"])){  }
```